# Need to make command in batch script invisible to user

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need help making `GPupdate /force` fully invisible to the user.

I've seen this in the past. Currently it answers a question to not log the user off the PC automatically but I would like to have the batch close visually but finish the gpupdate in the background.

```
@echo off
Title Internet Explorer Full Reset

::Close Internet Explorer tasks
taskkill.exe /f /im iexplore.exe

::Wait
timeout /t 4

::Performs reset on all settings for Internet Explorer
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /f

::Wait
timeout /t 2

::Clear all temporary internet files
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8

::Clear all cookies
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2

::Clear all form data
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16

::Wait
timeout /t 1

:: Set IE to always check for new versions of pages automatically
::reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /V SyncMode5 /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f

::Wait
timeout /t 1

::Enable favorites bar in Internet Explorer
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MINIE" /V "LinksBandEnabled" /D "00000001" /F

::Enable menu bar in Internet Explorer
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MINIE" /V "AlwaysShowMenus" /D "00000001" /F

::Enable command bar in Internet Explorer
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MINIE" /V "CommandBarEnabled" /D "00000001" /F

::Enable status bar in Internet Explorer
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MINIE" /V "ShowStatusBar" /D "00000001" /F

::Relaunch Internet Explorer
start iexplore.exe

::Update Group Policy to bring all Internet Explorer settings back into compliance
echo N | gpupdate /force

::Schedule task to reboot at 11:59PM
::schtasks /create /sc once /tn restart /tr "shutdown -r -f ""restart""" /st 23:59

::Message To User
msg * "Please restart your computer to complete configuration changes when you are next able."
```

Comment: If you close the window you will also close the running script. Your solution is to either minimise the window or to hide the window utilising another programming language/third party utility.

Comment: isn't there a way to tell a command to run in the background instead of the foreground?

Comment: Not without using another scripting language like VBscript, or a third party program.

Comment: If async ok for you `gpupdate /force /wait:0`
If minimized in another window ok for you `start /min gpupdate /force /wait:idntknow`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a program from a batch file without having the console open after the program start?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324539/how-can-i-run-a-program-from-a-batch-file-without-having-the-console-open-after)

Comment: a lot of duplicates: [How to call CMD without opening a window](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4277963/995714), [Launch a program from command line without opening a new window](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12010103/995714), [Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](http://superuser.com/q/62525/2413860)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a simple VBScript for cases like this. Use the command `start "" "directory\update.vbs"`. The contents of the VBScript (named update.vbs) are as follows:

```
Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 12 

strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup") 

Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_ 
objConfig.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW 
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process") 
errReturn = objProcess.Create("DIRECTORY\update.bat", null, objConfig, intProcessID)
```

Please note that you will have to replace `DIRECTORY\update.bat` with the file directory and name of your batch file. This should run it completely silently (user doesn't see a thing).